# Is a relation with two attributes always in Boyce-Codd Normal Form (BCNF)?

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory, relations

I went through some tutorials on BCNF and got that a relation with two attributes is always in BCNF.

#### My question

What if a relation with two attributes has no prime or non-prime attributes? That is, the attributes A and B do not determine each other and are simply in 1NF. From 2NF onward, the question of prime and non-prime attributes appear.

Anybody there to clarify the matter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "A 3NF table that does not have multiple overlapping candidate keys is guaranteed to be in BCNF".
With only 2 attributes, it is impossible to have multiple overlapping composite candidate keys.
The case that you are presenting for 'has no prime or non-prime attributes' is not even in 1NF.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form

Comment: [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/first-normal-form.htm) says that in 1NF, presence of primary key must be ensured while [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) talks about atomic, single values in the domain of an attribute but not about primary key. I'm confused.

Comment: Other websites also talk about the primary key (single or composite) to be one of the fundamental criteria to be in 1NF. Thus in a 2 attribute relation, if A->B and not vice-versa, then it is definitely in BCNF. Am I correct?

Comment: What does this mean *"What if a relation with 2 attributes has no prime or non-prime attributes?"* An attribute is either prime or non-prime. If the relation has 2 attributes then either both of them are prime, or just one (so the other is non-prme) or none of them (so both non-prime).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Sorry for my confusing statement. I meant to say that both the attributes are non-prime i.e., there is no determinant attribute.

Comment: To be in 1NF you must have an identifying attribute, a key. without it you will allow duplicate rows.
Date's definition for 1NF is that if and only if the table is "isomorphic to some relation" = it satisfies the following conditions:
1- There's no top-to-bottom ordering to the rows.
2- There's no left-to-right ordering to the columns.
3- There are no duplicate rows.
4- Every row-and-column intersection contains exactly one value from the applicable domain.
5- All columns are regular.

Comment: @SQLRaptor I agree with all your comment with the minor correction that a key can be empty (no attributes). It is a bit degenerative case but still such a relation satisfies all your 5 criteria. (All attributes would be non-prime, there would be max 1 rows so no duplicates, etc).

Comment: "a relation with two attributes is always in BCNF" False. If {} determines a column--ie the column has the same value in every row--in a table that can hold more than 1 column--ie {} isn't a/the CK--then a table is not even in 2NF.